# C# class indexer method call (log)

Tags: c#, logging, methods, delegates, indexer

I'm trying to implement my own solution for logging. Everything works fine except one thing, that just doesn't want to work out.
I have a class (Log), which has methods to log to file etc.
I can use it like Log.Debug(message, args), but thats not enough for me.

Sadly in C# we can't overload the call operator to be able to do something like Log(message, args).
Therefore I've searched on the web and found out about the indexer.
My idea would be now to do something like:

Log[loggingMode](message, args).

But I just can't get it working. I currently have delegate, a method and the indexer, which look like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Delegate for logging function, used by the indexer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mode">The logging mode.</param>
    /// <param name="message">The message to log.</param>
    /// <param name="args">The args for the message (String.Format).</param>
    public delegate void LogDelegate(string mode, string message, params object[] args);

    public LogDelegate this[string mode]
    {
        get
        {
            return LogIndexer;
        }
    }

    public void LogIndexer(string mode, string message, params object[] args)
    {
        lock (_Lock)
        {
            _queue.Enqueue(new LogEntry(String.Format(message, args), mode));
        }
    }
```

Now my question is, how can I pass the one argument of the indexer (mode) to the function, so that I can call it like:

Log"debug";

Comment: What's wrong with `Log.Debug()`?

Comment: Not to be negative, but if I were you, I'd stop right there and look at [Nlog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) frameworks.

Comment: Log.Debug is fine, but why not try more?
This whole thing is just for learning purpose, it's not going to be used in production code.

Answer (score 0):

`this[string mode]` getter should use its `mode` parameter to return a lambda with this mode:

```
public delegate void LogDelegate(string message, params object[] args);

public LogDelegate this[string mode]
{
    get
    {
        return (message, args) => LogIndexer(mode, message, args); 
    }
}
```